# Solve robust minimax optimization problem in two subsequent steps?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve a robust optimization problem (worst-case optimization) of the form

$$
\min_{x} \max_q f(x,q) \tag{1}
$$

with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $q \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ where $q_i \in [\underline{q}_i, \overline{q}_i]$ and $\underline{q}_i < \overline{q}_i \,\forall i \dots m$. The variables in $x$ are the desicion variables, the $q$ are uncertain parameters (box-uncertainty).

Assume now we can analytically solve the following problem

$$
M(q) = \min_x f(x, q) \tag{2}
$$

and i.e. derive the minimum $M(q)$ of $f$ over $x$ as a function of the parameters $q$. Further assume I can then solve the following optimization problem

$$
\max_{q} M(q). \tag{3}
$$

**Question**: Is the solution to $(3)$, computed with the solution of $(2)$ also a solution of $(1)$? I.e., can I solve a problem like $(1)$ by first finding a parameter dependent minimizer for $x$ and then a parameter combination $q$ that is a maximizer for this minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem), if $f$ is continuous function which is concave in $q$ and convex in $x$ (roughly speaking), then 
$$
\min_x\max_q f(x,q)  =\max_q\min_x f(x,q)=\max_q M(q)
$$
holds. Hence in this case, your method can solve the problem. However, in general cases, we can say at most
$$
\min_x\max_q f(x,q)  \ge\max_q\min_x f(x,q),
$$ and equality may not hold. In this case, your method does not give the solution.

Comment: note that the minimax theorem only applies if the domain of either $x$ or $q$ is compact (which holds for $q$ here), if both domains are convex, and if the function is lower semicontinuous & quasiconvex in $x$ and upper semicontinuous & quasiconcave in $q$

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. One more question, what if $f$ is both concave and convex (i.e. linear) in $q$?

Comment: @SampleTime then it is concave in $q$ and satisfies that part of the conditions.